# sqlplus how to find details of the currently connected database session

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have very recently started to work on oracle databases. Generally I have many sqlplus windows open to different oracle databases. When switching from one sqlplus session to another, how can i view the current session details for each sqlplus session ? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: found it using sys_context function [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions184.htm#g1513460) eg : select sys_context('USERENV','db_name')  from dual; or more simply from v$ view...select name from v$database; I think v$views are generally restricted to DBAs therefore sys_context will be the best option.

Comment: If this is what you want, then you can do `select * from global_name`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this one [`(c) Tanel Poder`](http://blog.tanelpoder.com/contact/). You may either run it from your glogin.sql (so these settings will update each time you connect, or just run it manually. Notice `host title` command - it changes your sql*plus console window title with session information - extremely useful with many windows open simultaneously.

```
-- the Who am I script

def   mysid="NA"
def _i_spid="NA"
def _i_cpid="NA"
def _i_opid="NA"
def _i_serial="NA"
def _i_inst="NA"
def _i_host="NA"
def _i_user="&_user"
def _i_conn="&_connect_identifier"

col i_username head USERNAME for a20
col i_sid head SID for a5 new_value mysid
col i_serial head SERIAL# for a8 new_value _i_serial
col i_cpid head CPID for a15 new_value _i_cpid
col i_spid head SPID for a15 new_value _i_spid
col i_opid head OPID for a5 new_value _i_opid
col i_host_name head HOST_NAME for a25 new_value _i_host
col i_instance_name head INST_NAME for a12 new_value _i_inst
col i_ver head VERSION for a10
col i_startup_day head STARTED for a8
col _i_user noprint new_value _i_user
col _i_conn noprint new_value _i_conn
col i_myoraver noprint new_value myoraver

select 
    s.username          i_username, 
    i.instance_name i_instance_name, 
    i.host_name         i_host_name, 
    to_char(s.sid)          i_sid, 
    to_char(s.serial#)      i_serial, 
    (select substr(banner, instr(banner, 'Release ')+8,10) from v$version where rownum = 1) i_ver,
    (select  substr(substr(banner, instr(banner, 'Release ')+8),
            1,
            instr(substr(banner, instr(banner, 'Release ')+8),'.')-1)
     from v$version 
     where rownum = 1) i_myoraver,
    to_char(startup_time, 'YYYYMMDD') i_startup_day, 
    p.spid              i_spid, 
    trim(to_char(p.pid))        i_opid, 
    s.process           i_cpid, 
    s.saddr             saddr, 
    p.addr              paddr,
    lower(s.username) "_i_user",
    upper('&_connect_identifier') "_i_conn"
from 
    v$session s, 
    v$instance i, 
    v$process p
where 
    s.paddr = p.addr
and 
    sid = (select sid from v$mystat where rownum = 1);

-- Windows CMD.exe specific stuff

-- host title %CP% &_i_user@&_i_conn [sid=&mysid ser#=&_i_serial spid=&_i_spid inst=&_i_inst host=&_i_host cpid=&_i_cpid opid=&_i_opid]
   host title %CP% &_i_user@&_i_conn [sid=&mysid #=&_i_serial]
-- host doskey /exename=sqlplus.exe desc=set lines 80 sqlprompt ""$Tdescribe $*$Tset lines 299 sqlprompt "SQL> "

-- short xterm title
-- host echo -ne "\033]0;&_i_user@&_i_inst &mysid[&_i_spid]\007"
-- long xterm title
--host echo -ne "\033]0;host=&_i_host inst=&_i_inst sid=&mysid ser#=&_i_serial spid=&_i_spid cpid=&_i_cpid opid=&_i_opid\007"


def myopid=&_i_opid
def myspid=&_i_spid
def mycpid=&_i_cpid

-- undef _i_spid _i_inst _i_host _i_user _i_conn _i_cpid
```

Sample output:

```
17:39:35 SYSTEM@saz-dev> @sandbox
Connected.
18:29:02 SYSTEM@sandbox> @me

USERNAME             INST_NAME    HOST_NAME                 SID   SERIAL#  VERSION    STARTED  SPID            OPID  CPID            SADDR    PADDR
-------------------- ------------ ------------------------- ----- -------- ---------- -------- --------------- ----- --------------- -------- --------
SYSTEM               xe           OARS-SANDBOX              34    175      11.2.0.2.0 20130318 3348            30    6108:7776       6F549590 6FF51020

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
```

Comment: thanks, it does an excellent job by changing the window titles. Now I can simply select the right sqlplus window from windows taskbar.

Answer (score 28):

```
show user
```

to get connected user

```
 select instance_name from v$instance
```

to get instance or set in sqlplus

```
set sqlprompt "_USER'@'_CONNECT_IDENTIFIER> "
```

Answer (score 19):

I know this is an old question but I did try all the above answers but didnt work in my case. What ultimately helped me out is

> `SHOW PARAMETER instance_name`

Answer (score 12):

```
select sys_context('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME') from dual;
```

&

```
select instance_name from v$instance;
```

will give you the instance name. 
You can also use `select * from global_name;` to view the global name of the instance.

Comment: The `SHOW PARAMETER` approach requires query access to `v$instance`, but this `SYS_CONTEXT` approach does not. (+)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select * from v$session where sid = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID');
```

You might also be interested in [this AskTom post](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:446220075876#5821366700346599437)

After seing your comment, you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM global_name;
```

Comment: thanks cade, but I think best response is from "be here now", see my comment there. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from v$session
where sid = to_number(substr(dbms_session.unique_session_id,1,4),'XXXX')
```

Comment: select sid from v$mystat where rownum = 1? ;)

Answer (score 0):

We can get the details and status of [session](https://ora-data.blogspot.in/2016/11/query-session-details.html) from below query as:

```
select ' Sid, Serial#, Aud sid : '|| s.sid||' , '||s.serial#||' , '||
       s.audsid||chr(10)|| '     DB User / OS User : '||s.username||
       '   /   '||s.osuser||chr(10)|| '    Machine - Terminal : '||
       s.machine||'  -  '|| s.terminal||chr(10)||
       '        OS Process Ids : '||
       s.process||' (Client)  '||p.spid||' (Server)'|| chr(10)||
       '   Client Program Name : '||s.program "Session Info"
  from v$process p,v$session s
 where p.addr = s.paddr
   and s.sid = nvl('&SID',s.sid)
   and nvl(s.terminal,' ') = nvl('&Terminal',nvl(s.terminal,' '))
   and s.process = nvl('&Process',s.process)
   and p.spid = nvl('&spid',p.spid)
   and s.username = nvl('&username',s.username)
   and nvl(s.osuser,' ') = nvl('&OSUser',nvl(s.osuser,' '))
   and nvl(s.machine,' ') = nvl('&machine',nvl(s.machine,' '))
   and nvl('&SID',nvl('&TERMINAL',nvl('&PROCESS',nvl('&SPID',nvl('&USERNAME',
       nvl('&OSUSER',nvl('&MACHINE','NO VALUES'))))))) <> 'NO VALUES'
/
```

For more details:
https://ora-data.blogspot.in/2016/11/query-session-details.html

Thanks,