# How to Track Oracle Users logging in to a DB using a procedure?

Tags: database, oracle

So I know to track via the audit connect and triggers option .But can we implement a procedure.

I get an error at v$session(I think its a view and not a table)...any workaround?Thanks!
code:

```
create or replace procedure logon_audit_proc 
is
  v_user varchar2(100);
  v_machine varchar2(100);
  v_sid number;
  v_serial number;

  cursor c1 is
  SELECT osuser, machine, sid,serial# FROM **v$session**;   

BEGIN
  open c1;
  loop
    fetch c1 into v_user,v_machine,v_sid,v_serial;
    exit when c1%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line('****');
    dbms_output.put_line('The emp name is '||v_user);
    dbms_output.put_line('The emp name is '||v_machine);
    dbms_output.put_line('The emp name is '||v_sid);
    dbms_output.put_line('The emp name is '||v_serial);
    dbms_output.put_line('****');
  end loop;
  close c1;
END;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  This is a lot like the question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541990/sqlplus-how-to-find-details-of-the-currently-connected-database-session.

Comment: Please describe why the built-in auditing feature doesn't satisfy your requirements.

Comment: @hillbillyToad, those options where reviewed but we are trying something which requires if this can work as a procedure.while the problems of a proc is that users who have already logged-in and off before the proc is run will not be captured..but thanks for asking

Comment: If the user executes a stored procedure, this will get captured by the audit trail. If it's not, it might be a setup issue, and I would consult Support or try the OTN Forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session likely does not have a direct grant on the object, which is necessary when using it in a definer's rights procedure.  Run this grant as SYS first, and then recompile:  `grant select on sys.v_$session to <test schema>;`

Also, the cursor-open-fetch-close method is slower and more complicated than an implicit cursor:

```
begin
  for sessions in (SELECT osuser, machine, sid,serial# FROM v$session) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(sessions.osuser);
    --...
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: thanks! but I think the result returns multiple rows so used explicit cursor, hmm the grant select ..is still not working for me.

Comment: What error do you get?  Also, implicit cursors are still preferred when multiple rows are returned, since Oracle will automatically bulk collect the data.

Comment: well as you can tell I'm sort of a noob still learning the ropes.. so I'm trying to run this on my PC (oracle, I have installed) so its <test schema> is scott(right?).the error is SQL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges..since its my own system(shouldn't I be the system admin and therefore have the privileges)..Thanks for taking time to help...

Comment: Did the grant work?  To run the grant, you'll probably need to start SQL*Plus from the command line like this: `sqlplus / as sysdba` and then run the grant.  I can't tell you who the user is, I'm not sure where you want this procedure installed.  If it's a local instance you will be able to make this work, it's just a question of granting the correct privileges, which can be tricky.

Comment: Your IDE probably needs to enable DBMS_OUTPUT.  Some do it automatically, some require configuration or clicking a button to enable.  On SQL*Plus, you can enable it with `set server output on;`.