# show con_name command returns SP2-0158: unknown SHOW option "_name"

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm using SQL*PLUS with Oracle g11 express edition.

```
SQL> show con_name;
concat "." (hex 2e)
SP2-0158: unknown SHOW option "_name"
```

Why does this error happen?

Comment: That statement makes no sense with Oracle 11 as it does not have pluggable databases.

Comment: Thanks a lot @a_horse_with_no_name for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That's not a valid option in 11g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve041.htm#SQPUG124). It shows your current container, and multitenant databases weren't introduced until 12c.

The `CON_ID` and `CON_NAME` options [were added in Oracle 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SHOW.html#GUID-6BB1499D-E537-43D1-A209-401F5DB95E16).

Edit: if you want to display the database SID / Instance name, you have a couple options:

```
prompt &_CONNECT_IDENTIFIER.

select instance_name from v$instance;
```

[See also this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541990/sqlplus-how-to-find-details-of-the-currently-connected-database-session).